# Implementing PIPO in verilog

Tags: verilog, icarus

I am looking to implement a 32-bit Parallel in-Parallel out in verilog HDL. Here is the code I have written...

```
module pipo(input_seq, answer,reset, clock);
   input [31:0] input_seq;
   input        reset,clock;
   output [31:0] answer;

   always @ (reset)
     begin
        if(!reset)
          begin
             answer[31:0]<=1'b0;
          end
     end

   always @ (posedge clock)
     begin
        answer[31:1]<=input_seq[30:0];  
     end

endmodule
```

However this leads to the following error log( using `iverilog`):

```
pipo.v:10: error: answer['sd31:'sd0] is not a valid l-value in pipo.
pipo.v:4:      : answer['sd31:'sd0] is declared here as wire.
pipo.v:16: error: answer['sd31:'sd1] is not a valid l-value in pipo.
pipo.v:4:      : answer['sd31:'sd1] is declared here as wire.
Elaboration failed
```

What are the problems?

Comment: You should not split the reset logic of a register and the clocking logic of a register into seperate blocks. You should have one block `always @(posedge clock or negedge reset)`. In your design the clocking block will still be executed if the clock toggles while reset is asserted, which is not the correct way to model a flip flop.

Answer (score 5):

You are using `answer` as a register, but it's declared as a wire. `Wire` is something which connects two points, and thus does not have any driving strength. On the other hand `reg` can store value and drive strength.

Change declaration of `answer` to `reg` and it should help.

```
output reg [31:0] answer;
```

Comment: Here is the working code with a testbench on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/82)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you that when you are describing combo logic, use blocking assignment.

```
always @ (reset)
   begin
     if(!reset)
       begin
         answer[31:0]=1'b0; //blocking assignment
       end
   end

About this block:

always @ (posedge clock)
  begin
    answer[31:1]<=input_seq[30:0];  
  end
```

You can fix the errors by making the output `output reg [31:0] answer` and this will let you assign an output in an always block.